# target='_blank' i HTML form opens two tabs when enter key is pressed

Tags: javascript, html

I've never dealt with Javascript before, but I'm currently trying to create a search-bar for our website which contains a Javascript function as part of the HTML code.
I got the following code based on a search box generator for the product we use (Primo Library Search):

```
<!-- Script that converts the query string into valid parameter -->
<script type='text/javascript'>

function searchPrimo() {
document.getElementById('primoQuery').value = 'any,contains,' + document.getElementById('primoQueryTemp').value.replace(/[,]/g, ' ');
document.forms['searchForm'].submit();
}

</script>


<form id='simple' name='searchForm' method='get' target='_blank' action='https://bibsys-almaprimo.hosted.exlibrisgroup.com/primo-explore/search' enctype='application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8' onsubmit="searchPrimo()">
<!-- Customizable Parameters -->
<input type='hidden' name='institution' value='UBIS'>
<input type='hidden' name='vid' value='UBIS'>
<input type='hidden' name='tab' value='default_tab'>
<input type='hidden' name='search_scope' value='default_scope'>
<input type='hidden' name='mode' value='Basic'>
<!-- Fixed parameters -->
<input type='hidden' name='displayMode' value='full'>
<input type='hidden' name='bulkSize' value='10'>
<input type='hidden' name='highlight' value='true'>
<input type='hidden' name='dum' value='true'>
<input type='hidden' name='query' id='primoQuery'>
<input type='hidden' name='displayField' value='all'>
<input type='text' id='primoQueryTemp' value=''  style="margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 15px; padding-bottom:8px; padding-top:8px; width: 75%; resize: vertical;" placeholder=" Søk etter litteratur - tittel, forfatter eller stikkord">
<!-- Search Button -->
<input id="go" type="button" class="searchbutton" value="Søk" title="Søk" onclick="searchPrimo()" alt="Søk" style="height:35px;">
</form>
```

Originally the code was created with `target='_self'` in the `'simple'` HTML form. However, I would like the search to open up in a new tab and after some research on here found that it should be changed to  `target='_blank'`. Now the search box works well when the search button is clicked with a mouse, but when I do a search and click enter I get two tabs - one "correct" tab with the search and another blank tab. How can I change the code in order to not get the extra, empty tab when clicking enter? Thank you so much for your help.

EDIT:
Solved based on @OMi Shah's comment:
Add `preventDefault();` to `searchPrimo()` fn, change `type="button"` to `type="submit"` and finally remove `onclick="searchPrimo()"` from the button. –

Comment: It looks like I [can't reproduce](https://jsfiddle.net/qhofcne4/) your issue ..?

Comment: You have default form action and `onSubmit` action together, maybe this is the case?

Comment: @Teemu - Thanks for looking! Maybe you can't reproduce the enter-issue because this tool is blocking pop-ups? I got a "pop up blocked" message in Chrome/Brave the first time I tried due to two tabs opening at the same time.

Comment: @tarkh - Thanks for the comment! Yes, that might be the reason, but I'm not sure how to resolve it as I'm a true beginner in Javascript. I tried to remove the  `onsubmit="searchPrimo()"` part in the form - then the tab action works, but when pressing enter the search isn't performed (i.e. no values are entered into Primo for searching).

Comment: Add ``preventDefault();`` to ``searchPrimo()`` fn, change ``type="button"`` to ``type="submit"`` and finally remove ``onclick="searchPrimo()"``  from the button.

Comment: Nope, a new tab is opened when I click the submit button. The tool itself doesn't block pop-ups, it's your browser.

Comment: Good to know, @Teemu. I'm really new to these things :) I managed to solve the issue though - have edited the original post for others to see. Thanks for your help!